# How to read .txt or .doc file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, filereader

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html  and then I make this controller to display the file txt content which I call test.txt

```
class File_controller extends CI_Controller {
function __construct(){ 
parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
            $this->load->helper('file');    
    }
public function index()
{
    $string = read_file(base_url().'test.txt');
    echo $string;
  }

 }
```

when I am testing this in browser no error is found, but the program is not displaying my file txt content,so

1.how to display test.txt correctly?

2.what the meaning is this parameter:

```
'./path/to/file.php'
```

when I am using

```
read_file('./path/to/file.php');
```

Comment: `echo base_url().'test.txt';`

Comment: @zerkms, I want read file content, not path string

Comment: I understand that, my point was that the path is incorrect, which you could have realized if you tried to run what I suggested.

Comment: yes I will try, and actualy I have other question to you @Arcanyx. 
is it possible to read with other format such as microsoft word. now I get new knowledge about the diferent between read_file() and readfile().

Comment: Yes it is possible to read other formats, but you will need to use third party libraries for those - like for reading Microsoft Word there is the [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) https://phpword.codeplex.com/ library... and so on. Cheers!!

Comment: oopsss, I have try it but appear unknown text format . so I need 3rd party ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off edit your project index.php and set the environment to development so that errors are properly displayed. You do have an error its just suppressed with this change it will show you your errors. First one I can spot myself I think - the php function is actually `readfile()` not `read_file()`. For your use I think you will find `file_get_contents()` works better.

As regards your file path. As you have it your text file needs to be at the root of the project at the same level as your index.php file. It also will need to be readable. With error reporting in development mode you will get an error if any issues with path or permissions

Comment: you tell me other way with file_get_contents() method?

Comment: First just change your index.php file so you can see your error

Comment: you are correct, I just change  read_file to readfile() and work. thank you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the link https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html

> Note: The path is relative to your main site index.php file, NOT your
>   controller or view files. CodeIgniter uses a front controller so paths
>   are always relative to the main site index.

This means that

```
'./path/to/file.php'
```

will be the path in your directory relative to index.php
Lets suppose your main site is in "mysite" folder. So the URL might be http://localhost/mysite/ and let us say the text file('test.txt') is in the main directory.
So you will now access this path as

```
read_file('/mysite/test.txt');
```

Accordingly, the change in code.

Comment: You sure? If its relative to `index.php` which is in mysite folder then the function call would be `readfile('test.txt')` (No underscore in the function)

Comment: It should work. Did u try? Also the readfile is a php function and read_file is a codeigniter function...

Comment: That explains that. The poster accepted removing underscore as the solution hence why I pointed it out. No I didn't try it but a file relative to `index.php` wouldn't need the directory that `index.php` is in surely

Answer (score 0):

**Get / Set the content of the file**

Then using [file_get_contents you](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) can retrieve the content of the file.

and using [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) you can set the content of the file.

You can also check

- [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
- [fread](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)
- [fwrite](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)
- [fclose](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)